# Why %2020 is valid for long datatype when we pass from url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, urlencode

I Have created .net mvc action in my controller as follow

```
public ActionResult Action(long No)
{
        return View();
}
```

Now i'm run the project and hit following Url

http://localhost:64478/Home/Action/10

it works fine as simple is that

Now i'm hiting url http://localhost:64478/Home/Action/%1010

In this case it returns **Invalid request**

Now i'm hiting url http://localhost:64478/Home/Action/%2020

in this case it working fine but in the controller it give me a value 20

so,why it is behaving like this even though i have use datatype long then why it
accepting 
**%**

Answer (score 0):

`%20` in Url is considered as encoded value for empty space. So the default model binder ignores the space and binds the value '20' to the parameter in the controller.

On the other hand %10 is a different character which is not ignored and attempt to bind `10` with a prefix of a non-digit character to a `long` variable will result in error.